# Arrays with objects in c# OOP

Tags: c#, arrays, oop, object

I have got a problem with some code and it overwrites names for the previous objects that have been declared.

I cannot see a fix. I have tried to fix it many times and my class mates cannot find a fix and neither can my teacher.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OOP
{
    class Student
    {
        private static string name;
        private static DateTime DOB;
        private static int ID;
        private static double height;
        private static string tutor;

        public Student()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            //Console.WriteLine("This is for student: " + (count + 1));
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the student's name");
            name = Console.ReadLine();


            //tryagain:
            //try
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Date of Birth");
            //    DOB = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //    DOB = DOB.Date;
            //}
            //catch
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid date format");
            //    goto tryagain;
            //} 

            //Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Student's ID");
            //ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            //Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Student's Tutor");
            //tutor = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            //Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Student's height(cm)");
            //height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        public void DispayData()
        {            
            Console.WriteLine("Name- " + name);
            Console.WriteLine("Date of Birth- " + DOB.Date);
            Console.WriteLine("ID- " + ID);
            Console.WriteLine("Tutor- " + tutor);
            Console.WriteLine("Height- " + height);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of students");
            int numStuds = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Student[] studs = new Student[numStuds];
            for (int i = 0; i < numStuds; i++)
            {
                studs[i] = new Student();            
            }
            Console.Clear();
            for (int f = 0; f < numStuds; f++)
            {
                display(studs[f]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void display(Student stud)
        {
            stud.DispayData();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: What is the problem here? What do you want to fix? I can´t see any error.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  What does this code *do*?  What do you *expect* it to do?  When you step through in a debugger, where does the observed behvaior first differ from the expected behavior?  What does that exact line of code do?  What did you expect it to do?  Why?

Comment: Not a fix, but honestly I wouldn't put `Console` commands inside a constructor.  Instead do that in your loop and pass in the name.

Comment: Your properties are static, and also please don't do all that work in the constructor, nasty stuff!

Comment: Also if you want to check if parsing a date will work use `DateTime.TryParse` instead of catching an exception.  And use a loop, not a `goto`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the fields of the `Student` class are static and are, thus, shared among all instances of this class. So just remove `static` and it will work.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

Comment: Thank you so much that has fixed the problem i had

Answer (score 1):

Your `Student` members are static, which means (summed up) they are shared among all your `Student` instances.

Remove the `static` keywords and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thank you so much that has fixed the problem i had

Comment: @JacobBrewer you can accept [Armen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49941148/3283203)'s answer then; he was one minute faster than me.